# How get email from myself and chatpartner in app studio as parameter in my website url

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want like this in the picture below, the email from myself and from my chatpartner to send it in the url with parameter to display the site in the personaltab.
Is this possible ?

[image]

thanks for help.

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to get the Email address from both profiles in a chat to send it per url parameter that i can load the binded Website with data.

Comment: Hey@Amok Khan, the functionality you are trying to achieve doesn't seems to be feasible. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT  Thanks for reply. Do you know a way to get the email adresses?

Comment: You can get userEmail from MS Teams using Bot framework as mentioned below:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details